# Trying to make Jquery tell users that the username and password slot needs to be filled out

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make Jquery tell users that the username and password slot needs to be filled out. I can make the code show that the username isn't inputted but I cant get the password section to work. Here's what I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Jquery</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
          var user = $("#username").val();
            if(user.length == ""){
                $("#username").css("border", "1px solid red");
                $("#error").html("Please Enter A Valid Username").css("color", "red");
                $("#error").css("text-align","center");
            };
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#username").mousedown(function(){
            $("#username").css("border", "1px solid black");
            $("#error").html(" ");
            };
        });
        );
    </script>
    <div class="tee">
    <h1>Learning jQuery</h1>
    <p>With Charles Agbakwu</p>
    </div>
        <center><table>
            <tr><td>Username:</td></tr><tr><td><input id="username" name="username" type="text"></td></tr><br>
            <tr><td>Password:</td></tr><tr><td><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></td></tr><br>
            </table><br>
    <button>Submit</button></center>
    <h3 id="error"></h3>
    <h3 id="error2"></h3>
    </body>
    <center><footer><p>Agbakwu &copy;-2016</p></footer></center>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of mistakes in your code. You need to close all of your functions for everything to work properly, and you also don't have any code for detecting if the password field is empty.

Your `$(document).ready(function(){` isn't closed in the first part and in the second part you need to close the "ready" as well. So close with `});`.

I have corrected your code and created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rm4quqsw/1/). This also has the part for the password field. You will see it by the comment.

As a small tip, you don't need two separate `$(document).ready` events or two different `<script>` tags. Keep everything in one.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I had a brainfreeze for a bit. Totally forgot to add features for password haha.

Answer (score 0):

```
I made it a little better

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Jquery</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var user = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val(); //define password variable
    if (user.length === 0 || password.length == 0) {

      $("#error").html("You Must Enter Both Username and Password").css("color", "red");
      $("#error").css("text-align", "center");

    };
if (password.length !== 0) {
      $("#password").css("border", "1px solid black");
    }else{
       $("#password").css("border", "1px solid red");  
    };
if (user.length !== 0) {
      $("#username").css("border", "1px solid black");
    }else{
        $("#username").css("border", "1px solid red"); 
    };
      return false;
  });

  $("#username").mousedown(function() {
    $("#username").css("border", "1px solid black");
    $("#error").html(" ");
  });
});
    </script>
    <div class="tee">
    <h1>Learning jQuery</h1>
    <p>With Charles Agbakwu</p>
    </div>
        <center><table>
            <tr><td>Username:</td></tr><tr><td><input id="username" name="username" type="text"></td></tr><br>
            <tr><td>Password:</td></tr><tr><td><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></td></tr><br>
            </table><br>
    <button>Submit</button></center><br>
    <center><span id="error"></span><span id="error2"></spam></center>
    </body>
    <center><footer><p>Agbakwu &copy;-2016</p></footer></center>
</html>
```